# Secure user-provided filename

Tags: python, file, security, directory

Part of my app requires the client to request files. Now, a well-behaved client will only request files that are safe to give, but I don't want a user to go about supplying `"../../../creditCardInfo.xls"`, instead. What's the best practice for/simplest way to secure a filename to make sure that no files are served that would be higher than a certain point in the directory hierarchy? First instinct is to disallow filenames with `..` in them but that seems... incomplete and unsatisfactory.

The current questions about filename safety on SO focus on making a writable/readable filename, not ensuring that files that shouldn't be accessed are accessed.

Comment: Define “secure”. Not passing files from a higher level of hierarchy is the only criterion?

Comment: @kirelagin: hmm.. i suppose they should only be able to request files from a given `resources` directory, but in that directory they can access whatever they like. should also disallow getting files from other drive letters if the server's running on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running in a UNIX variant, you might want a [chroot jail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) to prevent access to the system outside your application.

This approach would avoid you having to write your own code to deal with the problem and let you handle it with infrastructure setup. It might not be appropriate if you need to restrict access to some area within the application as it changes what the process thinks is the system root.

Comment: You could really have your "user file" in the chroot jail and the "program files" outside? Say I have a web application running in chroot jail, how could this app access its configuration file (or a template file, or whatever file) _outside_ the jail?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it would work, provided that `open` uses the same mechanism to resolve paths as `os.path.abspath`. Are there any flaws to this approach?

```
import os

def is_safe(filename):
    here = os.path.abspath(".")
    there = os.path.abspath(filename)
    return there.startswith(here)

>>> is_safe("foo.txt")
True
>>> is_safe("foo/bar/baz")
True
>>> is_safe("../../goodies")
False
>>> is_safe("/hax")
False
```

Comment: The approach seems fragile. I think it would be difficult to guarantee it's correct in the face of symlinks (especially symlinks to directories in internal components of the pathname), bind mounts, etc... One way around that to improve it somewhat is to use the result of `os.path.abspath` in the actual `open`, not just in the safe check. But more concretely, your function considers `/a/foobar` safe if the pwd is `/a/foo`, which I think is a problem since `/a/foobar` is not inside the directory `/a/foo`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a way to find the canonical(*) path of a file. That is with `..`, `.` and symbolic links removed. That is the role of [`os.path.realpath`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath)

```
>>> os.path.realpath(".")
'/home/sylvain'
>>> os.path.realpath("..")
'/home'
>>> os.path.realpath("./Documents/../..")
'/home'
```

`realpath` will follow symlink and "reduce" the path as well:

```
sylvain@daal:~$ ln -s /etc/password z
sylvain@daal:~$ python 
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 26 2010, 22:31:48) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.realpath("z")
'/etc/password'
>>> os.path.realpath("z/..")
'/etc'
>>> os.path.realpath("./Documents/../z/..")
'/etc'
```

... whereas `normpath` is easily abused:

```
>>> os.path.normpath("./Documents/../z/..")
'.'
```

Once you have the canonical name, you could easily check if the user should have access to the requested file. Say by comparing to a white-list.

---

(*) A file may have different path but only one canonical path.
See http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-the-difference-between-absolute-relative-and-canonical-path-of-file-or-directory/60 for more info.

Comment: Actually, no, that is the role of `os.path.normpath` which is calles by `os.path.abspath`. But, yes, resolving symlinks is also a good idea.

Comment: @kirelagin I was certain of myself. Now I have a doubt. So, I re-read the doc and it seems that `normpath` remove `..` only by string manipulation. As the doc says "This string manipulation may change the meaning of a path that contains symbolic links". By testing it seems that `realpath` first follow symlinks, then reduce the path if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I use, which I think has the benefits of giving easy control over access to the files, and preventing path manipulation.

When the user uploads the file:

1. Read the filename.
2. Generate a random alphanumeric token.
3. Save the file in a non-web accessible directory with a filename of that token.
4. Record the token and original filename in a database (along with who uploaded it, or some way of indicating who has permission to it).

To get the file:

1. The user requests the file via the token, not a filepath (mysite.com/download/587and83j21h1)
2. Use white-list validation on the token to ensure that it is alphanumeric.
3. Check the user's permission to the requested file.
4. Write the file to the response stream and set the filename equal to the original filename.